# Bigquery converting string to timestamp

Tags: google-bigquery, timestamp

Whats the best way to convert a string value like this to a timestamp?

"2021-05-11T02:00:03.4897671"

I tried the below

`select PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%E#S", "2021-05-11T02:00:03.4897671")`

But I get the following error

`Failed to parse input string "2021-05-11T02:00:03.4897671"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%E*S", "2021-05-11T02:00:03.4897671")
```